# PHP Urlencoded string not showing properly in SMS body

Tags: php, string, encoding

I am trying to send an encoded string appending it to an api url used fo sending BULK SMS. But not all characeters are being encoded correctly. I've tried using `utf8_encode`, `htmlentities` and `htmlspecialchars` on the string before using `urlencode` but that didn't work either. Since its an external api call they are only using urldecode for showing the string which I can not change. So what needs to be done to encode the special characters present in the following string to show it correctly in the resulting SMS.

**Example String:**

```
$message = '2016 brings with it a new year sale at “Orchid” & “home n décor”.';
```

> 2016 brings with it a new year sale at “Orchid” & “home n décor”.

**After applying urlencode and htmlentities**

```
urlencode(htmlentities($message, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'))
```

I get the following output -

> 2016+brings+with+it+a+new+year+sale+at+%26ldquo%3BOrchid%26rdquo%3B+%26amp%3B+%26ldquo%3Bhome+n+d%26eacute%3Bcor%26rdquo%3B.

When I try to use `urldecode` on this it gives me result as expected -

> 2016 brings with it a new year sale at “Orchid” & “home n décor”.

When I try to send the encoded output string as an url parameter and echo the parameter I get the exact same result, without even using the `urldecode`.

**But the problem is in my SMS body,** it is always showing in the following pattern -

```
2016 brings with it a new year sale at &ldquo;Orchid&rdquo; &amp; &ldquo;home n d&eacute;cor&rdquo;.
```

Why is it not showing the decoded string in SMS? How this can be done? Its showing normal encoded characters like & without any problem as its encoded to `%26`. But causing issues for double quotes or characters like `é`. Can anyone suggest any workarounds?

Comment: There are different encodings for SMS: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_Service#Message_size. Isn't there any good documentation about the API you are using?

Comment: @MatthiasW. no, no documentation is available, I just have the url and authentication, anyway thanks for the url, I am going to have a look at it now.

Comment: Prueva utilizando el método base64_encode($string), un poco más de referencia: http://php.net/manual/es/function.base64-encode.php

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
$message = "Message Text";
```

instead of:

```
$message = urlencode("Message Text");
```